# Java EE : Prevent application URL hacking

Tags: java, security, jakarta-ee, web-applications, web

I am working on an existing Web based application.

Now, I need to secure the application against what I think is called url hacking. For instance, if the customer with customerId 1 is logged in and viewing his profile, the following http get variable will be visible in the address field: customerId=1.
I need to prevent a customer from being able to set customerId=2 and see the profile of another customer.

The problem is that, the application is already in production and in good working condition, so the changes should be minimal with respect to this change.

How is this best achieved?

Any sugggestions/comments?

Comment: Take a look at [link](http://www.hdiv.org). It provides functionality that prevents users from changing request parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why do you give the id in the URL when the user should only be allowed to change his profile? I don't see any need for this. Rather get the current user from SecurityConext and display its profile on an URL without the id.

with the new information you gave in the comments I suggest sth. like this:

just check if the given orderid in the URL belongs to the current user.
You're saying you use "normal web based Application" so I assume Servlet/jsp based. In your servlet you would do something like this:

```
int orderId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("orderId"));
String username = request.getUserPrincipal().getName();
/*now you need to check if username match with the username of the order e.g. by using hibernate to get the order by id and check its user and if not throw PermissionDeniedException or similiar*/
```

Comment: quick google request came up with this, to do so in Spring:
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

Comment: I am sorry for the mistake , its not a Spring based Application , its a normal web based Application with JQuery as UI .

Comment: then use getUserPrincipal on HttpServletRequest

Comment: i dont know what you mean exactly , but i dont want to allow other Users to view other profiles rather than his .

Comment: I'm not sure I made myself clear here.
We are not displaying the id of the user that is logged in, this id is stored in a session.

Let me give another example.
Each customer has a number of orders. When a customer is viewing an order, the orderId is visible in the url. This is the id I don't want a customer to be able to tamper with. If a customer changes the orderId to an id of an order belonging to another customer, access should be denied.

Answer (score 0):

95% agree with Korgen's answer above.
5% - if you want to allow administrator access to edit user profiles using the same functionality just switch to UUID to identify edited user.

Comment: or give admin functionality only to users with specific admin role